# Install AppDynamics in OpenShift 4.X

Tags: openshift, appdynamics

I am looking for a way to install AppDynamics in a OpenShift Cluster.

Unable to find proper documentation on how to install and what tools need to be installed.

Should My Application Docker file also include any images related to AppDynamics

If anyone familiar with this please share some steps or provide reference to documents.

Answer (score 0):

Old docs: https://docs.appdynamics.com/22.2/en/infrastructure-visibility/monitor-containers-with-docker-visibility/use-docker-visibility-with-red-hat-openshift

New Docs: https://docs.appdynamics.com/22.2/en/infrastructure-visibility/monitor-kubernetes-with-the-cluster-agent

Note that there is not a prescribed way to instrument as such, you need to make some decisions.

i.e. (from the second doc link):

- The first decision is to use the officially released pre-built
  Appdynamics Operator images published on DockerHub and Redhat
  Registry or If you want to build a custom Appdynamics Operator image.
  See Build the Custom Cluster Agent Image.
- The second decision is whether to use the officially released
  pre-built Cluster Agent images published on DockerHub and Redhat
  Registry or If you want to build a custom Cluster Agent image. See
  Cluster Agent Container Image.
- The third decision is whether to install the Cluster Agent using the
  Kubernetes CLI or the Cluster Agent Helm Chart. See Install the
  Cluster Agent with the Kubernetes CLI and Install the Cluster Agent
  with Helm Charts.